# Docker error - Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file: write /dir : no space left on device

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, rasa

I'm getting this error when building the docker image. and I'm working on a non-root user of an ec2 instance

> Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /bot-data/tensorflow/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: no space left on device

when building the image of this Dockerfile.

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:1.8.0

# Use subdirectory as working directory
WORKDIR /chatbot/apps/docker_images/rasa/app

# Copy any additional custom requirements, if necessary (uncomment next line)
COPY actions/requirements-actions.txt ./

# Change back to root user to install dependencies
#USER root

# Install extra requirements for actions code, if necessary (uncomment next line)
RUN pip install -r requirements-actions.txt

# Copy actions folder to the working directory
COPY ./actions /app/actions

CMD ["start","--actions","actions"]
# By best practices, don't run the code with root user
#RUN groupadd -g 1000 nonroot && \
 # useradd -r -u 1000 -g nonroot nonroot
USER chatbot
```

> I'm new to docker, guidance to sort this out would be much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Space has run out on device probably. First we check residual images, using `df` command, the we list images and cleanup all those images that are not being used by our containers.

```sh
$ df
$ docker image ls
$ docker image ls | grep none | awk "{print $3}" | xargs docker rmi
```

This will clear all the images that show up as none.